# how to save an image from a url and save it in a specific folder

Tags: python, image, url

Hi I want to make a folder and save an image into that folder. Here is what I did but I get error:

```
 URL='https://storage.labelbox.com/ckh4cqkd7y8r30721vlr7m5he%2F7bc29750-7fcc-dbac-7683-1b67125d7afd-Y62Y62.jpg?Expires=1604685570096&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=sEhvkl3MUnT2iiuFZsvwFLqzAE8
 path1 = "/Users/naghmeh/Documents/medical/jadid/train/"+str(filename)
            try:
                os.mkdir(path1)
            except OSError:
                print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path1)
            else:
                print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path1)
            src_fname, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            save_fname = os.path.join(path1, os.path.basename(src_fname)+str(filename))
            img_data = requests.get(URL).content     
            with open('ImPath', 'wb') as handler:        
                mask=handler.write(img_data)
            mask.save(save_fname)
```

Error:
'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @larsks 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: You're assigning the return of `handler.write(img_data)` to the variable `mask`. `handler.write` returns an integer. You've already successfully written `img_data` to a file named `ImgPath`; what are you trying to do by calling `mask.save`?

Comment: It dose not save it in a folder that I created

Comment: I want to save it in save_fname

Comment: You're not telling it to save it in a folder. By calling `open('ImgPath', 'wb')`, you're writing to a file named `ImgPath` in your current directory. If you want to save it to `save_fname`, then use that variable in place of the string `ImgData`.

Comment: How I can change the directory to save_fname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the requests pkg:

```
import requests
image_url = "https://storage.labelbox.com/ckh4cqkd7y8r30721vlr7m5he%2F7bc29750-7fcc-dbac-7683-1b67125d7afd-Y62Y62.jpg?Expires=1604685570096&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=sEhvkl3MUnT2iiuFZsvwFLqzAE8"
path = "/Users/naghmeh/Documents/medical/jadid/train/asd.jpg"
request = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
with open(path, "wb+") as file:
  for c in request:
    file.write(c)
```

Comment: where is gonna be saved this image?

Comment: in path directory?

Comment: on the path "/Users/naghmeh/Documents/medical/jadid/train/". But you will probably need to put "C:\Users\naghmeh\Documents\medical\jadid\train\" if the python file isn't on the C: